# Output of Dudeney Numbers Isn't Complete

Tags: r

The output should show the seven dudeney numbers but only displays the first two. The first "if" condition does not evaluate to true even if the logic is correct. After the 99th iteration, the "if" condition turns FALSE, thereby the flow goes out. Tried several times but couldn't get the right outcome. Help!

```
library(pracma)

sum_of_digits<-0;
for(i in 0:(54^3)){
  if(nthroot(i,3)%%1==0){
    for(j in 1:nchar(i)){
      sum_of_digits<-sum_of_digits+as.numeric(substr(as.character(i),j,j))
    }
    if(nthroot(i,3)==sum_of_digits){
      print(i)
    }
  }
}

Output:
[1] 0
[1] 1
```

Comment: Please include the complete code in your question. What library does the `nthroot` function come from? And you don't define `sum_of_digits` before using it, which generates an error.

Comment: Edited. Kindly check!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is [floating point precision in R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

```
512 ^ (1/3)
[1] 8

512 ^ (1/3) == 8
[1] FALSE
```

**EDIT:** *as pointed out in a comment, a better fix is not to take the root at all*.

One ugly fix is to convert to the character representation of the number before testing for equality. Here I've used `DescTools::DigitSum()` to sum the digits of a number:

```
library(DescTools)

for(i in 0:54^3) {
  if(i ^ (1/3) == DigitSum(i))
    print(i)
}

[1] 0
[1] 1

for(i in 0:54^3) {
  if(as.character(i ^ (1/3)) == as.character(DigitSum(i)))
    print(i)
}

[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 512
[1] 4913
[1] 5832
[1] 17576
[1] 19683
```

Comment: What is the reason to first cube all numbers and then take their cube roots? It is much easier to take all numbers up to 54 (or 100 or ...) and loop through their cubes only:
`for (i in 1:54) if (DigitSum(i^3) == i) cat(i, i^3, '\n')`
It also avoids any 'floating point' problems from the beginning.

Comment: @HansW. quite right! I was just demonstrating using what was given in the question.